# Google Data Studio - "No Data Set Access" when displaying charts from PostgreSQL data source

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-platform, oauth-2.0, oauth, looker-studio

I'm hitting the following error when trying to display graphs with any of my PostgreSQL data sources.

```
No Data Set Access
Insufficient permissions to the underlying data set.
Access denied, please check your username and password.
Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.
```

I've whitelisted all Google Data Studio IPs on my PostgreSQL instance and I have no issue adding the corresponding data source to my Google Data Studio report (Add data >  PostgreSQL > Authenticate (using a PostgreSQL user) > Add) but every time I try to add a graph I get this error message.

Does anyone know what is going wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve the issue by granting all privileges on all tables to the user I use to authenticate on Google Data Studio. You need to run the following SQL query with a superuser (such as postgres):

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO my_user;
```

Another option to solve the issue is authenticating with a superuser (such as postgres).

In case some of you happen to be blocked by logs appearing on the charts, I recommend trying to add the data with a `SELECT * FROM my_table` in "CUSTOM QUERY" instead of using "TABLES". The logs are more explicit.